# Bootstrap-typeahead ajax post call not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using Bootstrap-typeahead for auto-complete feature.

This is my input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" value = "<%= searchText %>">
```

The ajax call:

```
      $('#search').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
          return $.ajax({
              url: "/query",
              type: "POST",
              data: {query :query},
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  process(data);
              }
         });
        } });
```

Getting the query:

```
app.post('/query', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body); });
```

This is not working.

When I make a POST call directly from Chrome console, it works. But using typeahead feature it fails to make the post call.

Anyone know what might be the issue?

Thanks!